# How can I know if July 2016 CU was correctly installed

Tags: 2013

I just installed July 2016 CU in SP 2013 Server Farm.
Build number is supposed to be 15.0.4841.1000

However on the patch installation status page I see things like this:

```
> 296DIIS03   Microsoft SharePoint Portal 
>  15.0.4571.1502 Installed   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3115293) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4841.1000 Installed   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3054937) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4737.1000 Superseded   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2956166) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4701.1001 Superseded   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2920804) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4693.1001 Superseded   296DIIS03   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2882989) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4631.1001 Superseded   296DIIS03   Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4571.1502 Installed   296DIIS03   Microsoft SharePoint Portal English Language Pack 
>  15.0.4571.1502 Installed   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3115293) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4841.1000 Installed   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3054937) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4737.1000 Superseded   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2956166) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4701.1001 Superseded   296DIIS03   Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2920804) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4693.1001 Superseded   296DIIS03   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2882989) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4631.1001 Superseded   296DIIS03   Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4571.1502 Installed   296DIIS03   Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013  
>  15.0.4571.1502 Installed   296DIIS03   Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552) 64-Bit Edition 
>  15.0.4571.1502 Installed
```

the first line on each groups shows 4841 which is the july 2015 CU, however the group name shows 4571.1502 which is Service Pack 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common question and annoyed for the sharepoint admins, reason build number is not supposed to be change after every cu.  in order to confirm that if CU installed properly.

- check from central admin> upgrade and migration as you shared the screen shot. If the job is listed here as installed that's mean it is
- you can also check from add remove program from the server and then under sharepoint check if ko is listed there.

Here is great article which explain about build number myth.https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/